# Can you create a mailing list based on tags

Tags: groups, smartgroups, mailing, tags

Is there a way to use tags, possibly multiple tags e.g. using the tags `Students` and `Attended Conference X`, to create a bulk mail to members who fit into just those two categories.

Answer (score 1):

Search Builder should let you say 'find Contacts who have this tag AND have that tag' and then set up the Smart Group from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Search - Advanced Search but note the AND/OR operator maybe doesn't work quite as you'd expect. It only works between different fields and within a single multiselect field it is always `OR`.

But you can do a workaround:

1. Go to Search - Find Contacts.
2. Pick your first tag.
3. From the actions dropdown in the result list, create a group, e.g. Student Group.
4. Go to Search - Custom Searches - Include / Exclude Search
5. For Include Groups choose your group.
6. Select "AND".
7. For Include Tags select your second tag.
8. From the actions dropdown in the result list either create a group for future use or you can choose to schedule/send an email.

Alternatively for steps 4-8 you can use Advanced Search instead of the custom search and put your group in the Groups field and your tag in the Tags field.

Comment: Would Search Builder give the expected outcome?

Comment: Ah I didn't think of that. Yes it seems to work. Do you want to add another answer?